# Vispy gloo can't draw GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP

Tags: python, opengl, glfw, pyopengl, vispy

I'm trying to set up a basic environment for pyGLFW + Vispy + PyOpenGL.
When trying to draw, I get

> RuntimeError: OpenGL got errors (periodic check): GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Traceback:

```
File "D:/Users/Emil/Documents/workspace/SynkFPS/newtest/start.py", line 109, in <module>
    win.run()
  File "D:/Users/Emil/Documents/workspace/SynkFPS/newtest/start.py", line 104, in run
    self.display()
  File "D:/Users/Emil/Documents/workspace/SynkFPS/newtest/start.py", line 96, in display
    self.program.draw(gl.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vispy-0.3.0-py2.7.egg\vispy\gloo\program.py", line 491, in draw
    self.activate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vispy-0.3.0-py2.7.egg\vispy\gloo\globject.py", line 56, in activate
    self._activate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vispy-0.3.0-py2.7.egg\vispy\gloo\program.py", line 209, in _activate
    self._activate_variables()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vispy-0.3.0-py2.7.egg\vispy\gloo\program.py", line 316, in _activate_variables
    attribute.activate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vispy-0.3.0-py2.7.egg\vispy\gloo\globject.py", line 56, in activate
    self._activate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vispy-0.3.0-py2.7.egg\vispy\gloo\variable.py", line 335, in _activate
    self._update()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vispy-0.3.0-py2.7.egg\vispy\gloo\variable.py", line 362, in _update
    self.data.activate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vispy-0.3.0-py2.7.egg\vispy\gloo\globject.py", line 56, in activate
    self._activate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vispy-0.3.0-py2.7.egg\vispy\gloo\buffer.py", line 180, in _activate
    self._update_data()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vispy-0.3.0-py2.7.egg\vispy\gloo\buffer.py", line 202, in _update_data
    gl.check_error('periodic check')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vispy-0.3.0-py2.7.egg\vispy\gloo\gl\__init__.py", line 181, in check_error
    raise err
RuntimeError: OpenGL got errors (periodic check): GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

What do I do? I have tried without drawing and it works fine.
The problem start on win.run(), then self.display() in Window -> self.program.draw(...) in display().

```
#!usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import division
import ctypes as ct

import OpenGL.GL as gl
import pyglfw.pyglfw as glfw
import numpy as np
from OpenGL.arrays import vbo
from vispy.gloo import Program, VertexBuffer, IndexBuffer, VertexShader


# String globals -
# --------------

VERTEX_SHADER = """
    uniform float scale;
    attribute vec4 color;
    attribute vec2 position;
    varying vec4 v_color;
    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = vec4(scale*position, 0.0, 1.0);
        v_color = color;
    }
    """
FRAGMENT_SHADER = """
    varying vec4 v_color;
    void main()
    {
        gl_FragColor = v_color;
    }
    """


class Window(object):
    """ Open glfw window """

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        # Basic setup
        # -----------
        glfw.init()

        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.aspect = self.width / self.height

        glfw.Window.hint(context_version=(4, 2))
        self.win = glfw.Window(self.width, self.height, b"sample test example")
        self.win.make_current()

        # Data, FIXME will be implemented outside this class
        self.data = np.zeros(4, [("position", np.float32, 2),
                                 ("color", np.float32, 4)])
        self.data['color'] = [(1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 1)]
        self.data['position'] = [(-1, -1), (-1, +1), (+1, -1), (+1, +1)]

        # OpenGL Initialization
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        gl.glEnable(gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0)
        gl.glPolygonOffset(1, 1)
        gl.glEnable(gl.GL_LINE_SMOOTH)
        gl.glBlendFunc(gl.GL_SRC_ALPHA, gl.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
        gl.glLineWidth(0.75)

        self.program = Program(VERTEX_SHADER, FRAGMENT_SHADER, count=4)
        self.program['color'] = [(1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 1)]
        self.program['position'] = [(-1, -1), (-1, +1), (+1, -1), (+1, +1)]
        self.program['scale'] = 1.0

        # Set glfw callbacks
        self.win.set_mouse_button_callback(self.on_mouse_button)
        self.win.set_key_callback(self.on_keyboard)
        self.win.set_window_size_callback(self.on_resize)

    def on_mouse_button(self, win, button, action, mods):
        print("[!]Pressed. Button:{} Action:{} Mods:{}".format(button, action, mods))

    def on_keyboard(self, win, key, scancode, action, mods):
        print("[!]Pressed Key:{} Scancode:{} Action:{} Mods:{}".format(key, scancode, action, mods))
        if action == glfw.Window.PRESS:
            if key == glfw.Keys.LEFT:
                pass
            elif key == glfw.Keys.RIGHT:
                pass
            elif key == glfw.Keys.ESCAPE:
                self.win.should_close = True

    def on_resize(self, win, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.aspect = width / height
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height)

    def display(self):
        self.program.draw(gl.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP)

    def run(self):
        glfw.set_time(0.0)
        while not self.win.should_close:
            t = glfw.get_time()
            glfw.poll_events()
            gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
            self.display()
            self.win.swap_buffers()


win = Window(640, 480)
win.run()
```

Comment: Note that Vispy has a backend for glfw. So you can do `app.use('glfw')` and then follow the approach in other Vispy examples. Further, try turning on gl debugging by putting this on top of the file `gloo.gl.use_gl('desktop debug')`. Vispy will then check for errors on each API call instead of once each draw, which should provide a more meaningful error message.